# How to hide a column in devexpress gridview on page load?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to hide one column from my gridview using devexpress page load event.

This is my view code:

```
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="7" Caption="Action">
    <DataItemTemplate>
        <dx:ASPxButton runat="server" ID="btnEdit" Text="Edit" OnClick="btnEdit_Click" AttId='<%# HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("Id").ToString()) %>'></dx:ASPxButton>
    </DataItemTemplate>
</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

How to write code to hide this column on page load event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you just want it to be invisible at start you could just add the Visible attribute

```
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="7" Caption="Action" Visible="False">
```

if you really want to to set it in code behind

```
ASPxGridViewCustomers.Columns["Action"].Visible = false; // ASPxGridViewCustomers is the Id of the ASPxGridView
```